# DR1 is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method' .. this

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code.. and it showes that DR1 is a variable and is being used as a method please can some one explain this for me and how can i fix it i need to get the data from the database and post it on a label

```
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("sql connection");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from request where reqNo = '" + lbl_reqNoV.Text + "', sqlConnection1";
    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    SqlDataReader DR1;
    DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DR1.Read();

         if (DR1.HasRows)
        {
            lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1("ReqNo");
   }
```

Comment: Try to access your property like this lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1["ReqNo"];

Comment: tried still nothing still shows an error

Comment: getting same error?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\Planning application\Purchase\Default.aspx.cs 49 35 Purchase                                  getting this error now

Comment: Aside from anything else, I would **very strongly** urge you to switch to using parameterized SQL *immediately* to close the SQL injection attack vulnerability your code currently has.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
 lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1("ReqNo");
```

`DR1` is a variable.  But `DR1()` uses the syntax of a method call.

You probably meant this:

```
lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1["ReqNo"];
```

Or possibly

```
lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1.GetString("ReqNo");
```

Comment: i have tried this but still shows an error and it doesn't work is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: @forbiddenghost: "still shows an error" doesn't tell us anything about what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

As you were getting *Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    E:\Planning application\Purchase\Default.aspx.cs    49  35  Purchase getting this error now*

you have to use ToString() for the value read from the datareader. Kindly see the below code for reference

```
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=[Server];Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from request where reqNo = '" + lbl_reqNoV.Text + "'";
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        SqlDataReader DR1;
        DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (DR1.HasRows)
        {
            DR1.Read();
            lbl_reqNoV.Text = DR1["ReqNo"].ToString();
        }
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Try explaining what you changed and why.

Comment: He was getting this error
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\Planning application\Purchase\Default.aspx.cs 49 35 Purchase getting this error now

Comment: I mean you should [edit] your answer to contain an explanation. "Try this" is not an answer.

Comment: I was actually trying to help him through comment section. but since he was getting further errors, i created a code snippet for his reference. Please see my edit now :)

Comment: @Ratheesh  i have tried what you suggested and now it works but another issue is appearing it says in correct syntax but is it ??                  
Incorrect syntax near ','. 
 Source Error: 



Line 36:         sqlConnection1.Open();
Line 37:         SqlDataReader DR1;
**Line 38:         DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();**
Line 39:         DR1.Read();
Line 40: